# Laravel mix not building css files properly when more than one js file is given to build

Tags: laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

My css and js used to get build perfectly from the laravel-mix. But as soon as I added one more js to it, the css files are getting build empty.

```
mix.js('resources/admin/js/app.js', 'public/admin/js')
.js('resources/customer/js/app.js', 'public/customer/js')
.sass('resources/admin/sass/app.scss', 'public/admin/css')
.sass('resources/customer/sass/app.scss', 'public/customer/css')
.webpackConfig({
  optimization: { minimize: true , minimizer: [ new TerserPlugin({parallel:true})] },
     devtool: "inline-source-map"}).version();
```

With the above code the css files generating are empty (only one single line comment is getting generated).

Removing any of the js file from the build process gives the complete perfect css files.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this

```
// For admin
mix.js('resources/admin/js/app.js', 'public/admin/js')
.sass('resources/admin/sass/app.scss', 'public/admin/css')
.webpackConfig({
  optimization: { minimize: true , minimizer: [ new TerserPlugin({parallel:true})] },
     devtool: "inline-source-map"}).version();

// For customer
mix.js('resources/customer/js/app.js', 'public/customer/js')
.sass('resources/customer/sass/app.scss', 'public/customer/css')
.webpackConfig({
  optimization: { minimize: true , minimizer: [ new TerserPlugin({parallel:true})] },
     devtool: "inline-source-map"}).version();
```

Do same with your sass files

Comment: I want js files to be in separate folder and have separate file. They are different for admin base and customer base.

Comment: Then you can make two different mix for them like my updated answer 
check that